# Extend and encrypt a public hotspot signal

Tags: wireless-networking

The building I live in is next door to a park with a public hotspot.  I would like to extend this unlocked wifi signal as well as encrypt it, so I can utilize, it without sharing it with my neighbors :)
Please advise on hardware, software and procedure…  Can I use any old router or should I buy a special extender?   which type of extender/router allows me to encrypt an unlocked wifi signal? 
please note that this questiosn has not been asked beforeon this forum
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Despite the OP's edit making no difference to the question, I believe the duplicate refers to improving reception. This OP wants to extend the range of the hotspot to his own premises and encrypt access to it. Question has been edited accordingly

Comment: You do understand that even if you encrypt the connect to the access point you connect to the original connection is still unencrpted and thus ALL of your traffic in unencrypted right?  What you want to do is pretty pointless since it adds no security at all.

Comment: the reason wh  want to encypt my boosted signal is becasue I am concerned about security;  I just don't want to share the boosted signal for selfish reasons. please advise accordingly

Comment: CORRECTION: the reason why I  want to encypt my boosted signal is NOT because I am concerned about security; I just don't want to share the boosted signal for selfish reasons. please advise accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You could buy a router that supports being a wifi client an let it share the network to the lan ports. But no you cant just encrypt a network thats intentionally open.

But:
 You can use VPN Provider of your choosing for having a encrypted tunnel through that foreign untrusted network to the vpn provider, which provides you internet access through the tunnel.

I know, lots of VPN provider names, but I havent tested one for about 3 years so I dont have any specific knowledge about which is best (for you).